# How do I fix a composer error related to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to create a project using Git bash.

However, during the creation it is coming up with error's relating to to `autoload.php`.

**Errors :**

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\onetoone\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\onetoone\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

and

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\onetoone\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\onetoone\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

I've tried composer install which does no difference and also gone into the project directory and tried composer install however I'm having no luck and it shouldn't be this complicated to get working.

[image: Error in Git Bash]

How can I resolve these errors? I've looked through other problems relating to this however nothing is working.

Comment: composer dump-autoload ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `composer.json`.

Delete "vendor" directory, then run

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

If you have just cloned Laravel from Github, change your directory to the right one (containing your project) then run the first command as above.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct Server Requirements for Laravel; *the `failed to open stream:` error indicates that either **OpenSSL** and or **Mbstring PHP** Extension(s) particularly are not enabled if installed and available.*

Below are the requirements for Laravel:

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

Check and enable the required extension(s) in your `php.ini` and do remember to restart your server.

After that, run the following command:

```
composer update
```

That should enable you resolve the errors you are getting and get your application working.